# Run a script only when a specific Google Form is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've seen a few posts on this site asking similar questions, but I haven't found them to be very helpful. I have a Google Sheet which is receiving data from two different Google Forms. I want to run a script after someone submits the first form and not the other. On the trigger set up page you can only do "onFormSubmit." Can anyone explain to me (in detail) how I can have only one Form trigger the script?

The similar questions have all sent me to external sites to read "documentation"; I'm not a programmer, so I need a more thorough explanation of how to do this; I really don't understand very many terms, nor do I understand how to set this up.

Comment: "Can anyone explain to me (in detail) how I can have only one Form trigger the script?"  This may lead to close this question as "need more focus".  Do you already know that there are two types of on form submit installable triggers, one for spreadsheets another for forms? Do you already know who to use event object of installable triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the value of range field in onFormSubmit trigger event object for a Spreadsheet.  `e.range.getSheet().getName()` will provide the name of the response sheet and from that you can determine which form caused the trigger.

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=="Your Forms Response Sheet Name") {
    //run your script here
  }
}
```

[form submit event  object for spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)